# How to save booleans so i can use them when coming back to this activity?

Tags: java, boolean, android-studio-3.0

I am making a study choice test app. In this test, where you should be able to go back when you want to change an answer. Each question is a different activity.
In order to go back, and accept different input, my program needs to recognise what button has previously been pressed (if any), hence the code below.

The main thing i don't know how to figure out, is how do i modify this code, so it can save booleans for when you come back to this page.

```
//defining the booleans    
public boolean Clicked1 = false;
public boolean Clicked2 = false;
public boolean Clicked3 = false;
public boolean Clicked4 = false;

//defining my button
mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            if (Clicked1 || Clicked2 || Clicked3 || Clicked4){
                if (Clicked1) {
                    NextPage();
                }else if (Clicked2) {
                    Clicked1 = true;
                    Clicked2 = false;
                    NextPage();
                }else if (Clicked3){
                        Clicked1 = true;
                        Clicked3 = false;
                        NextPage();
                }else {
                        Clicked1 = true;
                        Clicked4 = false;
                        NextPage();
                }
            }else {
                Clicked1 = true;
                NextPage();
            }
        }
    });`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for are SharedPreferences. Data in SharedPrefences are saved in your app internal storage. So to start :

Initialize your SharedPreferences in `onCreate()`.

**Saving data in SharedPrefences**

```
// You need a static String variable for identifying your preference 
public static final String CHOICE_PREF = "MyOptions";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(CHOICE_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putBoolean("Clicked1_state", Clicked1); //("Id key", Value)
editor.putBoolean("Clicked2_state", Clicked2);
editor.putBoolean("Clicked3_state", Clicked3);
editor.putBoolean("Clicked4_state", Clicked4);
editor.apply();
```

**Getting data from SharedPrefences**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(CHOICE_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE); 
Boolean Clicked1 = prefs.getBoolean("Clicked1_state", false);//This will get the last state of Clicked1 
Boolean Clicked2 = prefs.getBoolean("Clicked2_state", false);
Boolean Clicked3 = prefs.getBoolean("Clicked3_state", false);
Boolean Clicked4 = prefs.getBoolean("Clicked4_state", false);
```

So, ideally, when your activity enters `onStop()`, save your preferences and when your activity `onResume()`, retrieve your saved preferences.

More info about SharedPrefences : [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

Comment: does that mean in my NextPage() function i should also save the preferences?

Comment: @lucer Well, I don't know if `NextPage()` changes to another activity or just replaces a fragment. Seeing from your code, `NextPage()` is the last function you use, so you can definitely save pour preferences inside `NextPage()`.

Comment: Yes nextpage() is indeed my function that goes to another activity.
Thanks a lot I will try to get it working!

Comment: @lucer Let me know if you need more help :)

Comment: @lucer don't forget to press the accept button if Thomas has fixed your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using **annonimous class**. This is how the `new View.OnClickListener(){` construct is called. When you access variables from within annonymous class they need to be final. In your case theClicked1/2/3/4 variables are not final and this is why you are not able to modify and preserve the result.

You have couple of options:

**Alternative** 1 Use a state pattern. Instead of anonymous class create a real class that extends from View.OnClickListener  create a State class where your shared state is and share it in between the action listener and the class holding the buttons. This way your state will be accessable and modifyable.

Here is an article describing the State pattern https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-state

Here is on very detailed implementation of the state pattern using swing. https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00538334/PDF/SwingStates.pdf

**Alternative 2** would be to use some sort of storage to hold the state in the form of a file, or a database.